# References are transformed in lowercase using IEEbib.bst

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style

I am writing a paper using IEEEbib.bst. I remark that references are changed in lowercase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx,array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\newcommand{\subfigANDtitle}[2][.2\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}} #2 \end{tabular}}

% % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% % % % % % % % % % % %


% Example definitions.
% --------------------
\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}

% Title.
% ------
\title{xxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz.}
%
% Single address.
% ---------------
\name{xx,yy}
\address{xxxxxx,yyyyyy}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\section{section1}
adaafasfaa \cite{4761608}
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{exbib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if the bibliography is created in bibtex, you can put braces around the elements in titles that need to remain uppercase.  for example, if "IEEE" is in a title, you would need to enter it as `{IEEE}` to ensure that it doesn't get lowercased.  (what is converted to lowercase is based on a combination of publisher practice and type of bib entry.)

Comment: Only words in the `title` field are being converted to lowercase, right? As barbara beeton has already commented, you should place curly braces around the words that *must not* be converted to lowercase. In the example at hand, I assume this applies to the first word, viz., "3D".

Comment: @Mico, yes of course like 3D become 3d

Comment: @phdstudent - So write the field as `title = "{3D} human posture ...",`.